# HDD smart error on boot but ok on usb

Tags: hard-drive, sata, smart

I have a secondary HDD (not the one with the OS) and the computer is giving me a S.M.A.R.T. error when I try to turn on the computer with it as an internal HDD. When I force the computer to boot anyway, Windows won't recognise the HDD. However, I have tried connecting the same HDD as an external disk (via USB), and it works without any problem: S.M.A.R.T. seems ok (according to CrystalDisk software) and the Windows error checking tool is OK. Why can the disk be faulty when connecting a second internal HDD via SATA?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other post, connection via USB (Carrier) is slower than bus-connected.  This is likely why errors are showing up when internally connected.

After you have forced it to boot bus-connected, try disk checks again including CHKDSK and the disk manufacturer's hardware test application.

These may be able to show you errors.

I would not trust the drive at this point. Be very certain to back it up completely right away.

Comment: Finally I have replaced the drive. This problem was added to some other problems with the disk, so best to move to a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the drive is in your computer as an internal drive, your computer is relying on its BIOS to interface with the drive. If your BIOS is unable to support this drive, or your BIOS settings are incorrect for the drive, you may encounter errors.

When using the same drive as an external drive via USB, you are not reliant on your computer's BIOS to interface directly with the drive, which explains why you are successfully bypassing the problem that way.

You may be able to reconfigure your BIOS settings to work correctly with the drive. Check the drive manufacturer's website for related information.

You may also be able to resolve the issue by updating your computer's BIOS, if a newer version is available.